# How to prove the next statement?

Tags: geometry, integration

Let's have the parabola 
$$
4ay = x^{2}.
$$ 
It rolls along the x-axis. How to prove that it's focus moves along the trajectory of the catenary, 
$$
y = a\cdot ch \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)?
$$

Comment: Unfortunately, I even don't know how to begin to solve this task.

Comment: Since the curve is rolling along the $x$-axis, I would start by finding the coordinates of the point on the original parabola that touches the $x$-axis at $(c,0)$. This will involve understanding the arc-length of segments of the parabola.